# What's the best way to make an std::string out of one char?

Tags: c++, c++11

There are plenty ways to make an std::string from one char.

- `std::string(1, ch)`
- `std::string() + ch`
- `std::string(&ch, 1)`
- `std::string {ch} \\ c++11`

I wonder which one I should prefer.

Comment: To answer the efficiency question, a benchmark would be your friend here.

Comment: ***I wonder what's the best way in terms of efficiency*** Would it really matter? I mean how many billions of times do you need to do that in your program?

Comment: The question is do you really need to make a string from a single character only?  What are you going to use it for?

Comment: You would normally want the same idea both for character variables and character literals - thus std::string(&ch, 1); doesn't cut it - since std::string(&'a', 1) doesn't work. In addition it doesn't look good to use more than operation - and std::string()+ch; uses two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remember that source code communicates to readers, not primarily to the compiler.

Thus you should strive for clarity, and mostly leave the optimizations to the compiler.

Therefore, as the one expression that doesn't involve extraneous issues, and therefore communicates the intent most clearly, `std::string{ ch }` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

"A picture speaks a thousand words", as one saying goes.

The c++ equivalent might be "the interface declaration ought to be a picture".

We can create a very lightweight function, which will almost certainly be inlined wherever it's used, adding no overhead and telling the complete story:

```
namespace notstd {

    using std::to_string;

    // interface conveys all the information we need.
    inline std::string to_string(char c)
    {
        // implementation is not actually that important
        return { c };
    }
}
```

The use case then becomes self-explanatory code:

```
auto s = notstd::to_string('c');
```

and it can be used in template-land:

```
template<class T>
doSomething(T const& v)
{
    using notstd::to_string;

    auto s = to_string(v);  // will also use ADL when necessary

    somethingElse(s);
}
```

Comment: You can prevent this function accepting e.g. a `double` actual argument by making it a template and enable-if it. But I think it's already slight overkill. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did think about the overkill aspect, but when we are writing generic code, we often create little adapters like this in order to poly-fill missing free-function interfaces. On balance, my view is that it improves (or at least does not reduce) clarity by stating intent, while extending the generic capabilities of std/ADL to_string. If I saw this in non-generic code I'd be agnostic. If I saw it in generic code I would consider it necessary in order to do whatever `somethingElse` is to chars.

Comment: Oh. For that purpose should add `using std::to_string` in the function template. Unrelated: I have encountered a problem with this approach so that I've landed on calling it `string_from`, with a generic default that delegates to `std::to_string`, but I'm sorry I can't recall the problem exactly (I tried a few possibles now, but it all worked).